# Keep Java Program Running Without Standard In

Tags: java, daemon, kill, bufferedreader

What I would like to accomplish is to start a Java program and have it keep running until the user kills it with a control-C. I realize that it is possible to do this by creating a BufferedReader and having it endlessly loop while reading the BufferedReader, but what I am doing involves me backgrounding the Java program (e.g., java -jar app.jar &) which kills standard in so that method would not work. I've read a bit on Java's daemon threads, but I also do not think that is the correct solution in this instance because I want the JVM to stay alive.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: If you background it, there is no way a user can interrupt it with CTRL-C ... but you can use kill ...

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this approach? Maybe backgrounding the program is not the right solution? Or maybe there is a better way to interrupt the program than Ctrl-C?

Comment: Can you say more about how you "want the JVM to stay alive" and thus are ruling out a daemon solution?  I'd like to read more about that.  (I was going to point you at the [Apache Commons Daemon component](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/) because I happened to read about that today.  It became my hammer, and your question is looking a lot like a nail.  =)

Comment: I see what you're saying about Ctrl-C. What I want is to have a Java application start a thread which does not die if I background it from the command line. The issue I currently have is backgrounding the program closes standard in, so reading from a BufferedReader does not work. Is the Apache Commons Daemon component the correct solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're launching the java program from a different process perhaps? A potential option may be integrating the [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp) ? Depending on what you are doing, licensing may be an issue, and you probably wouldn't kill the process with a ctrl-c, but it's a thought (in addition to the others given above).

Comment: The real issue is that standard in closes when I background the program. I don't believe the Java Service Wrapper would help that.